# Laravel: redirect to constructed url

Tags: php, laravel

E.G. we want to redirect to

`http://example.loc/common/{$alias}`

Suppose that `http://example.loc/common/` route has a pseudo name - `common`. All that remain is build the `Redirect::route` expression; it would be something like

```
Redirect::url('common/{$alias}'); // warning: invalid code
```

Comment: You can also use `"common/{$alias}"` (double quotes) if you don't want to concatenate, so that it looks cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have any of below methods i guess.

```
$data = '1234';
return redirect('common/'.$abc);
```

or

```
$url = 'commom/'.$data;
return Redirect::to($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to a url writing it as a string

```
$alias = 'some-url';
redirect('common/'.$alias);
```

Also, if you know the route and it's a named route, you can use

```
redirect()->route('named.route', $alias);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, it tells `Route [named.top] not defined.` when I tried `redirect()->route('named.top', $alias);`. The `top` is defined as `Route::get('/', ['as' => 'top', 'uses' => 'MainController@renderTopPage']);`. What I missed?

Comment: So, your route name is `top`, not `named.top`. `named.route` was just an example on how you can use dot notation in name to organize them